# Updater user with multiple roles

Tags: user-roles

I have searched the net for explanations, but I only find my own question without any real answer. Like this one:
[Adding multiple user roles dynamically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/306225/adding-multiple-user-roles-dynamically)

I need to dynamically assign more than one role to some users. However, it seems that WordPress core is built for only one role per user. I have used Members plugin to define more roles. And they seem to reside in wp_options, along with the 'native' ones. But it seems impossible to update the user->role with an array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roles are assigned one per user. That's default for WordPress. Instead of using roles, I recommend using [capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) to keep track of different types of users. You can assign multiple capabilities per user and set some default capabilities for the role.

See: [`add_cap()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) and [`remove_cap()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap)

Comment: Seems like a good piece of advice. I'll try that one.